# Multiplication quiz

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

> Write a Java application program that will help an elementary school student learn multiplication. Use a Random object to produce two positive one digit integers. The program should then prompt the user with a question, such as
> How much is 6 times 7?
>
> The student then inputs the answer. Next, the program checks the student’s answer. If it is correct, display one of the following the messages and ask another multiplication question.
>
> Responses to a correct answer:
>
> 1. Very good!
> 2. Excellent!
> 3. Nice work!
> 4. Keep up the good work!
>
> If the answer is wrong, display one of the following message the messages and also provide a correct answer.
>
> Responses to an incorrect answer:
>
> 1. No. Please try again.
> 2. Wrong. Try once more.
> 3. Don't give up!
> 4. No. Keep trying.
>
> You could use random-number generation to choose a number from 1 to 4 that will be used to select an appropriate response to each answer and use a switch statement to issue the responses.
>
> After the user enter -1 to exit the program. The program should print out all the questions, answers to those questions, remark to the wrong questions, statistics information about number of questions answered and answered incorrect, and a little remark. If the user has more than one third of the questions are wrong the remark should randomly choose from “Responses to an incorrect answer”, otherwise it should randomly choose from “Responses to a correct answer”.

This what I got so far. I don't know if I need to make and array of the recent randomNumbers and if I do, How would I call it ? a for loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.SecureRandom;


class Main 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] correct = {"Very Good!", "Excellent", "Nice Work!", "Keep up the good work!"};
    String[] wrong = {"No. Please try again.", "Wrong. Try once more.", "Don't give up!",        "No. keep trying."};

   int rand1 = 0;
   int rand2 = 0;
   int user = 0;
   int anwer = 0;

   do
   {
     rand1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);
     rand2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);

     System.out.printf("How much is %d times %d ?",rand1,rand2);

     System.out.println();

     System.out.print("Enter your answer (-1 to exit): ");

     anwer = rand1 * rand2;
     user = input.nextInt();

     if (anwer == user)
     {
        System.out.println(correct[randomNumbers.nextInt(4)]);
     }

     else
     {
        System.out.println(wrong[randomNumbers.nextInt(4)]);

        System.out.printf("The correct answer is %d", anwer);

        System.out.println();

     }

   } while  (user != -1);


 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "make and array of the recent randomNumbers?" It looks like your assignment suggests that you make an array of responses to user input. Is that what you meant?

Comment: There are two things to consider. First, you need to keep track of a number of answers that is unknown at the start of execution. You could use arrays for this, but generally a List is a better solution, as they don't have a predetermined size and won't require resizing if the user enters more answers than you're expecting. Second, your assignment asks to keep track of both the questions asked, the answers given, the remark used in response, and print out statistics, this means that your array or List should contain result objects of some sort.

Comment: I mean if I do use array to track the unknown numbers and the users answer, how would I output this: For example, after the user input "-1" to exit the code it should output the past multiplication question, let's say the question is "How much is 2 times 2?" then the user answers, then exits it should output this:
"The questions generated by the system are:
2 * 2 = 4 Your answer was 0, which is incorrect.
"